# Как для большого количества label сделать общую процедуру?

Tags: delphi, label

У меня есть "Таблица Менделеева" на которой огромное количество label представляющих имена химических элементов (lb+имя_элмента), мне нужно для такого большого количества label сделать 2-3 общие процедуры обработки

Comment: "огромное количество label представляющих имена химических" - 118?

Answer (score 0):

Например, при программном создании вы можете задать обработчики

```
lbl[i] := TLabel.Create(Self);
lbl[i].Parent...
lbl[i].SetBounds...
lbl[i].OnClick := lblsClick;
```

Если вы потрудились и всё сделали вручную, то пройдите по компонентам (или контролам) родителя, задавая обработчик нужным компонентам:

```
for cm in Components do begin
   if cm.Name.StartsWith('lbl') then
     TLabel(cm).OnClick :=  lblsClick;
end;
```

Comment: А как это сделать чтобы работала при входе на форму? Ну или пока она активна

Comment: Я не понял вопроса

Comment: Ну я перехожу с главной формы на форму где располагается таблица Менделеева и Должен по нажатию на Label(Элемент периодической таблицы), обработать sql запрос и вывести на Panel поля таблицы бд Name_of_Elem и Atom_weight.Так куда и как я должен записать обработчик

Comment: В OnCreate формы с таблицей назначить обработчик

Comment: так то никто не мешает массово выделить на форме все лейблы и вписать всем разом обработчик